# Convergence K-Means Unsupervised Image Clustering Pre-trained Keras Grayscale Image

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, k-means

I'm new to image clustering, and I followed this tutorial:

Which results in the following code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
directory = './imageSample'
vgg16_feature_list = []
    
for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    if(filename != '.DS_Store'):
        img_path = directory + '/' + filename
        print(img_path)
        img = image.load_img(img_path)#color_mode = "grayscale")
        img_data = image.img_to_array(img)
        img_data = np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=0)
        img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)

        vgg16_feature = model.predict(img_data)
        vgg16_feature_np = np.array(vgg16_feature)
        vgg16_feature_list.append(vgg16_feature_np.flatten())

vgg16_feature_list_np = np.array(vgg16_feature_list)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=0).fit(vgg16_feature_list_np)
```

However, I'm receiving this error:

**ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters (1) found smaller than n_clusters (5). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
return_n_iter=True)**

I wonder if it is because of the sample images? They look like these, of 80x80 pixels, there are 52 of them:
[image]

I tried changing the color mode to grayscale, however I received
**IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 1** instead.

Kindly advice if such clustering is feasible with my dataset. Will it work if I expand the dataset to perhaps 100-200 images? or if there is any other approach I should look at to group the dataset. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**
Seems that the real issue is same image features extracted, so I've move this to another post: [Keras Same Feature Extraction from Different Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632757/keras-same-feature-extraction-from-different-images)

Comment: Can you check the shape of the vgg16_feature_list_np before clustering? Generally, the warning occurs when you have num of clusters> num of samples.
it should be (num of samples,dims) i.e, (52,4096)

Comment: @cerofrais the shape of vgg16_feature_list_np is (52, 2048), it should be ok right?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: You might need to check some items in the feature list. If most of them are identifical, it could result in such an error message. The root cause of this problem could be the failure of load_image.Bytheway, the default image size is 224 x 224, while your images are with 80 x 80. That could be a problem too.

Comment: @Frank you are right, i checked few items in the feature list, they are identical (!). is there a way to calibrate this? Or somehow the images are just too similar? Do you think it will change if I load the image in grayscale mode (but I have the above error for grayscale mode)? Thanks!

Comment: I think that two different images should have two differenet features out of VGG. You could change VGG to other models to see if other models also create identifical features. If they do, I think that the problem is on image loading. Maybe you could change the image loading mechanism to OpenCV.

Comment: hi @Frank, thank you for highlighting the real issue here, I've since created a new post since changing model and loading with opencv also resulted in the same feature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632757/keras-same-feature-extraction-from-different-images